# Illegal String offset error in view codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I try to load the data from database in views it is showing error :

```
A PHP ERROR WAS ENCOUNTERED

SEVERITY: WARNING

MESSAGE: ILLEGAL STRING OFFSET 'NAME'

FILENAME: CLIENT/LISTVIEW.PHP

LINE NUMBER: 7
```

when I `var_dump` the variable, its showing

```
STRING(1) "N"
```

in the result

This is in my controller file (client.php)

```
public function viewlistdetail()
{

      $id=base64_decode($_GET['id']);
    $this->load->helper('client');
    $this->load->model('client/Client_model');
    $this->Client_model->viewlistdetail($id);  
}
```

This is in my model file (client_model.php)

```
 function viewlistdetail($st)
{
    //echo $st;die;
    $data['page_title'] = 'List View';
    $data['detail']=$this->getlistdetail($st);

    $this->load->view('client/general/head',$data);
    $this->load->view('client/general/header');
    $this->load->view('client/listview',$data);
    $this->load->view('client/general/footer');
}
      public function getlistdetail($id){

       // $this->db->reconnect();
        try{

            $query1 = $this->db->query("SELECT id,name,detail,facility,address,city FROM listing WHERE id='$id'");
            $str1=array();

        if ($query1->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            $j=0;
           foreach ($query1->result() as $row1)
               {
                $str1=array("id"=>$row1->id,"name"=>$row1->name,"detail"=>$row1->detail,"facility"=>$row1->facility,"address"=>$row1->address);

                $str1['photo']=$this->getphoto($id);
                $str1['price']=$this->getprice($id);
                $str1['tag']=$this->gettag($id); 
                $j++;
               }
        }

        else
        {
            $str1="No record Found";

        }
        }
        catch (Exception $exd){
        $str1= "error";
        }
        return $str1;
    }
```

View File (listview.php)

```
    <h4><?php echo var_dump($detail['name']);?></h4>
    <span class="bussadd"><?php var_dump($detail['detail']);?><span>
```

Comment: What's the use of MVC in CI.  You are calling views from model class!! Why don't you call from controller??

Comment: can you post your array `var_dump($detail)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure this is your answer. I think you will get some idea with my answer.

Change your files to

in your controller `client.php`

```
public function viewlistdetail()
{

      $id=base64_decode($_GET['id']);
    $this->load->helper('client');
    $this->load->model('client/Client_model');

     $data['page_title'] = 'List View';
    $data['detail']=$this->Client_model->getlistdetail($id); 

    if(isset($data['detail']))
    {
    $this->load->view('client/general/head',$data);
    $this->load->view('client/general/header');
    $this->load->view('client/listview',$data);
    $this->load->view('client/general/footer');
    }
    else
    die('No list to display');

}
```

In Model page `client_model.php`

```
 public function getlistdetail($id){

   // $this->db->reconnect();
    try{

        $query1 = $this->db->query("SELECT id,name,detail,facility,address,city FROM listing WHERE id='$id'");
        $str1=array();

    if ($query1->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        $j=0;
       foreach ($query1->result() as $row1)
           {
            $str1=array("id"=>$row1->id,"name"=>$row1->name,"detail"=>$row1->detail,"facility"=>$row1->facility,"address"=>$row1->address);

            $str1['photo']=$this->getphoto($id);
            $str1['price']=$this->getprice($id);
            $str1['tag']=$this->gettag($id); 
            $j++;
           }
    }

    else
    {
        $str1="No record Found";

    }
    }
    catch (Exception $exd){
    $str1= "error";
    }
    return $str1;
}
```

Your view file

```
 <h4><?php var_dump($detail['name']);?></h4>
    <span class="bussadd"><?php var_dump($detail['detail']);?><span>
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Client::getlistdetail() in D:\xampp\htdocs\clubhouz\application\controllers\client.php on line 72

Its is showing this error

Comment: when i comment this line in controller
 // $data['detail']=$this->getlistdetail($st);

Now it is showing no list to display

Comment: Can you post your `$data` array here ?

Comment: but the error os still same....

A PHP ERROR WAS ENCOUNTERED

SEVERITY: WARNING

MESSAGE: ILLEGAL STRING OFFSET 'NAME'

FILENAME: CLIENT/LISTVIEW.PHP

LINE NUMBER: 7

Comment: $newdata=array("name"=>$title,
                           "detail"=>$desc,
                           "type"=>$pp,
                           "address"=>$add,
                           //"price"=>$price,
                           "facility"=>$ff,
                           "city"=>$this->session->userdata('city'),
                           "bussid"=>$bid['userid'],
                           
                            );
                            //print_r($newdata);die;
            
         $retval=$this->Client_model->save("listing",$newdata);

Comment: I asked you to post array which is returned from the `model` calss

Comment: $data = array(
                   'userid' => $encoded_id_array['id'],
                   'username' => $encoded_fn_array['username'],
                   'email' => $encoded_email_array['email'],
                   'validated' => true
                   );

but this was in comment....actually the code is written by someone else i have to re-code it as it is not working...i dont know whthr it is right or not and i am a newbie to it please guide accordingly

Comment: There is no value for `$data['name']` or $detail['name'] . dat's why it's showing warning.

Comment: means i should create an new array name data where its value feeded.....is this you are trying to say..??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65261/discussion-between-mahendra-and-geetika-joshi).

Comment: i dont have enough reputation to send message in the chat any other medium??

Answer (score 1):

The following code could work here. Try it to the view page.

```
<h4><?php echo isset($detail['name']);?></h4>
<span class="bussadd"><?php isset($detail['detail']);?><span>
```

or

```
<h4><?php echo isset($detail['name']) ? isset($detail['name']) : ''; ?></h4>
<span class="bussadd"><?php isset($detail['detail']) ? isset($detail['detail']) : '' ;?><span>
```